# Question related to equal Ranges and Null spaces of operators on the Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T_1, T_2\in\mathcal{L}(H)$ be two bounded operators on the infinite dimensional Hilbert space H.

My question is: If $R(T_1)=R(T_2)$ , then what could we say about $T_1,T_2$ ? Does there exist any relation between $T_1$ and $T_2$ ?

I know that when H is finite dimensional and $R(T_1)=R(T_2),$ then $T_1=T_2 S$  for some invertible operator $S \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and the converse is also true. Will this result hold for infinite dimensoinal Hilbert space. Provide some opinions.

Thanks.

Comment: If $R(T_1)=R(T_2)$ then it automatically implies $N(T_1^*)=N(T_2^*)$ from the relation $R(T)^\perp=N(T^*)$.

Comment: @NewB Thank you. Kindly look at my second question in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same trick seems to work for infinite dimensional Hilbert space when the o.n.b for $N(T_1)$ and $N(T_2)$ are of same cardinality.

Consider two orthornomal basis $\wedge_1$ and $\wedge_2$ for $N(T_1)$ and $N(T_2)$ respectively. Extend these bases to orthonormal basis $I_1$ and $I_2$ of $H$. Let $H_1=\overline{span\{I_1\setminus\wedge_1\}}$ and $H_2=\overline{span\{I_2\setminus \wedge_2\}}$. Notice that $T_1$ and $T_2$ restricted to $H_1$ and $H_2$ are injective map onto $R(T_1)=R(T_2)$ respectively (and hence isomorphism by open mapping theorem). Thus we can define a map $S:H_1\to H_2$ as $S(x)={T_2}_{|H_2}^{-1}{T_1}_{|H_1}(x)$. It is easy to check that this map is well defined, bijective, bounded and hence an isomorphism. Extend this isomorphism naturally to whole $H$ and then once can easily see that $T_1=T_2S$.

Infact $T_1=T_2S$ for some isomorphism $S$ forces that cardinality of o.n.b for $N(T_1)$ and $N(T_2)$ are same.